# AFNetworking and strange error -999

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, afhttpclient

I have strange problem with AFNetworking framework. This problem is not common, it happens sometimes and I can not find the reason. It works 5 times in row and the next time, on the same request it returns NSUrlErrorDomain -999.

```
    [self patchPath:path parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
           NSLog(@"OK");

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
           NSLog(@"ERROR");

    }];
```

Comment: I was reading this topic and It doesn`t help. Request is making on singleton instance so I can not release it, url address is valid because few times ago it worked for the same.